# Seeking benchmark dataset for election prediction

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, elections

What benchmark datasets are used for election prediction? Can anyone provide me a link to access such benchmark collection for future research work?

Answer (score 1):

I have never really looked for a generic data set as most election outcome predictions are purely statistical in nature.  If there is any secret sauce, it is usually in the sampling methodology and weighting but even these are pretty well known.  The polls are usually informative because the polling firms repeat the same poll daily or weekly over long periods.